# How do I "flip" the direction of a sequence $x+tv$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I "flip" the direction of a sequence $x+tv$?

Particularly I'm traversing the $x$-axis.

$t$ is time, $v$ is some fixed velocity.
$x$ is initialized to $x=0$.

Assume that we hit a "wall" at some $x$ and want to change direction of where $x+tv$ "goes".

IF this was $x+\Delta x$, then simply $\Delta x = - \Delta x$.
However, since $t$ must continue progressing to positive (cannot reverse time), then what do I need to do?

My intuition says to "figure out a way to 'count backwards' form the hit point". But this sounds a bit complicated.

Comment: Do you know where the wall is? (ie would a conditional evaluation of $vt$ make sense)

Comment: @KitterCatter Yes I know the $x$-coords of "walls".

Comment: Are you looking for something that is like you give me a time $t$, a speed $v$ and a starting position $x_0$ and I give you a final position $x(t;v,x_0)$? or just an update? (ie  would flipping the sign on $+vt$ be sufficient?)

Comment: @KitterCatter Flipping sign of $vt$ doesn't solve this, because consider e.g. wall at $x=5$. Initialize $x=0$, $\Delta t=1$, $v=1$. Counting $t$ in $x+tv$, we move: $0,1,2,3,4,5$, set $tv=-tv$, continue: $-6,-7,-8, ...$. When it should be $4,3,2, ...$.

Comment: How about after a wall hit, update $x$ to wall coord. E.g. above $x=5$. Then take $tv \space mod \space x = 6 \space mod \space 5$=1. And do $x-(tv \space mod \space x)=5-1=4$, then $5-2=3$, then $5-3=2$, ... I just don't get how the flipping of the sign should be reasoned. I cannot flip sign of $v$, because then the mod doesn't work. Perhaps I need to think that "well, we use the same line basically, but our start point and direction is not different.".

Comment: Also if we hit another wall back at $x=0$, then what? We have $x-(tv \space mod \space x)=5-5=0$, set $x=0$. Next $tv=11$. So one'd need to take $tv \space mod \space 10$ somehow, but now it starts to look complicated.

Answer (score 1):

We know the positions of the walls for this situation, call them $a_l$ and $a_r$. We also know the size of the box which is $L=a_r-a_l$. We have the starting position $x_0$.

Without loss of generality we could define our coordinate system such that the left most wall is at 0. Based on the length issue we know that our function of $t$ must be something like $x(t) = x(t) \texttt{ mod } 2L$, where $0-L$ is the positive heading toward a wall and $L-2L$ is coming back from the well, and $x(t) = x(t \texttt{ mod } \frac{2L}{v})$. (I think you noticed this in your comments)

I think this leads us to something like
$$x = \left\{ \begin{matrix}x_0+vt \mod L &\text{   If }t\leq\frac{L-x_0}{v}\mod\frac{2L}{v}  \\2L-x_0-vt \mod L &\text{ If } \frac{L-x_0}{v}<t\leq\frac{2L-x_0}{v}\mod \frac{2L}{v}\\x_0+vt \mod L&\text{If }t>\frac{2L-x_0}{v}\mod \frac{2L}{v}\end{matrix} \right .$$

Not the prettiest and you can simplify partially by instead starting with $x_0=0$ or shifting $t$ to represent that.